# Adding a centered shadow behind a css element

Tags: html, css

I am finally learning CSS, but I am stuck on adding a fading, centered shadow behind text.
I've tried using text-shadow and box-shadow, but I have been unsuccessful. What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have found some potential solutions that use really complicated css, but I am hopeful a simpler solution exists that I am just missing.
Here is my markup:

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.5em;
  right: 0;
}

#menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li:hover a,
#menu li.active a,
#menu li.active span {}

#menu li a,
#menu li span {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
}

#menu .active a {
  background: #2651a8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#menu .icon {}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">FIRST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">SECOND</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">THIRD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">FOURTH</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:before` and blur `filter`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: auto;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: currentColor;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover:before {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum.</a>
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. Is it possible to have it be permanent behind the button (i.e. not on hover)? I'm also struggling to get it to work with my existing css.

Comment: @theauzman just remove `:hover` or move the `opacity: .2;` to the selector above it. And if you're having trouble making it work, update your question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Box shadow ways.

```css
.cool-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.cool-content:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}

.cool-content.full:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cool-content">COOL CONTENT</div>

<div class="cool-content full">COOL CONTENT</div>
```